# Manually make entry in delayed jobs table from JAVA(MYSQL Insert statement) and queue processed by delayed_jobs ruby gem

Tags: java, ruby, delayed-job

Using rubygem in Rails we make entry in delayed_jobs table with syntax

```
 Delayed::Job.enqueue(MyJob.new(parameters), 0, 2.minutes.from_now, :queue => "queue1")
```

how to do same insert operation in delayed_jobs table using direct mysql statement. Mainly **handler** column, what value I have to insert and how to construct data?.

delayed jobs table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE  `schema1`.`delayed_jobs` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attempts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`handler` text NOT NULL,
`last_error` text,
`run_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`locked_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`failed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`locked_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`queue` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `delayed_jobs_priority` (`priority`,`run_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and class definition as follows

```
class MyJob < Struct.new(parameters)
 def perform

 end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar situation, I have made it work when by inserting a UTC_TIMESTAMP in the `run_at` column of delayed_jobs. So my sql looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO delayed_jobs (handler, run_at, created_at, updated_at) VALUES ('--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMailer
object: !ruby/class \'MyMailer\'
method_name: :welcome_mail
args:
- 123', UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP(), UTC_TIMESTAMP());
```

The worker will detect this record and run my method.

Answer (score 2):

The Handler column is a YAML serialized Ruby Struct. It tells DelayedJob worker which worker to invoke to process the job.

For example, if you have a job that converts video files, you might insert something like this in the handler column:

```
"--- !ruby/struct:VideoStreamer::ProcessVideoJob\nvideo_id: 68\n"
```

When DelayedJob takes this job from the queue it will call:

```
VideoStreamer::ProcessVideoJob.perform(video_id: 68)
```

It's also possible to serialize more complex ruby structs into the queue, but there is a size limitation in the handler field, so it's probably better and a whole lot easier to try to just pass id's in the queue instead of the actual objects.

To insert data to MySQL you use a regular `INSERT` statement.

Comment: thank you for your answer its helpful, I have updated question, Actually I need mysql insert query into delayed jobs